# How do I summon multiple mobs at once?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do you `/summon` multiple mobs at once?

I do not want to use any repeating redstone circuits, as they take up RAM and CPU storage.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: Yes i have, but i couldn't find anything, but thanks!

Comment: Great! So show us what you've tried, so we know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to summon multiple mobs at once?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191917/is-it-possible-to-summon-multiple-mobs-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

In 1.13+ versions of minecraft you still cannot `/summon` multiple entities, BUT you can execute a single command as multiple entities, which basically results in `/summon`-ing multiple entities with one command.

To summon 3 sheep at your current position you can run this command:

```
/execute as @e[limit=3] run summon minecraft:sheep ~ ~ ~
```

*Note: There have to be at least 3 entities (including players and items) in the world for this to actually summon 3 sheep*

If you want to summon multiple different entities with one command, then you can summon a falling block without specifying a `Time`, it will disappear after one tick. Set the mobs that you would like to spawn as passengers.
To summon two pigs and one enderman you could then use this command:

```
/summon minecraft:falling_block ~ ~ ~ {Passengers:[{id:"minecraft:pig"},{id:"minecraft:pig"},{id:"minecraft:enderman"}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

If you already have multiple mobs, you can use something like

```
/execute at @e[type=<mob_type>,distance=..10] run summon <mob_type>
```

If you for example want to summon 128 sheep, you can do this:

```
/summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep
```

Comment: ,,You can't" is not the right answer, logdotzip could do the same with only one command, that doesn't repeat itself, but thanks!

Comment: Really? In Vanilla Minecraft? Did he maybe summon a stack of mobs? I can imagine that there is a way to make the stack fall apart and make the intermediate mobs disappear, but since you were also concerned about performance, that's not an option. And if you've already seen it, why do you ask and not answer? Or have you forgotten how it works? In that case it would have been better to give more details about what you still remember about the video.

Comment: 1.13 syntax: `/execute at @e[type=sheep,distance=..10] run summon sheep`

Comment: Thanks. I didn't go through my answers with score of 1 or less, because they're just too many. Feel free to just edit the posts directly. The worst that can happen is that I revert it, but that's unlikely. I get a notification for edits to my answers.

Comment: Despite my high level of activity, I actually have <2K rep, and had inconsistent results from the suggested edit queue when I submitted 1.13-ification edits a year or so ago, so I've resorted to posting comments whenever I come across outdated answers in my patrol-old-[tag:minecraft]-question spree

Comment: Well, for my answers at least you can always just edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command for summon 2 zombies:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {BlockState:{Name:activator_rail},Time:1,Passengers:[{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"summon zombie ~ ~ ~"},{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"summon zombie ~ ~ ~"},{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"kill @e[type=command_block_minecart]"}]}
```

You can use this command for summon 3 zombies:

```
/summon falling_block ~ ~1 ~ {BlockState:{Name:activator_rail},Time:1,Passengers:[{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"summon zombie ~ ~ ~"},{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"summon zombie ~ ~ ~"},{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"summon zombie ~ ~ ~"},{id:command_block_minecart,Command:"kill @e[type=command_block_minecart]"}]}
```

and more...

It is good command. Because you can add nbt tags to your mob and set your mob location! But it is not easy command.

Comment: Using activator rails with command block minecarts! Genius, but probably clunky and overcomplicated for the situation. You can see that in the above answer, you can just summon the mobs directly on a `falling_block`.

Answer (score 0):

just do something like:

```
/execute @p run summon minecraft:sheep ~ ~ ~
```

in a repeating command block, then you want to copy paste that into some chain ones as well.